# Plugin for integrating SQLMAP with Burp Suite

Tags: java, sqlmap

I am trying to do SQL Injection using the SQLMAP Burp Plugin which I downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/gason/downloads/list. I have followed the steps for windows provided in http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/sqlmap-burp-plugin-2/. But when I am running the command provided, I am getting an error like:

**`Could not find or load main class "-classpath".`**

I have tried replacing the classpath with the path of the plugin, but this didn't help. Can someone please help me solve this thing? This is for Windows 7.